# What is the term for a system of equations that is known to have a solution that can be found in closed form?

Tags: terminology

Let $X = \{x_1,...,x_n\}$ be a set of variables and $F = \{f_1(\tilde{X}_1)=0,...,f_m(\tilde{X}_m)=0\}$ be a set of $m \ge n$ equations, each one a function of some subset $\tilde{X}_i \subset X$.  I know that my set of equations is sufficient for solving for all variables $x_i$, although some may be redundant.  Furthermore, I know that this solution can be found in closed form.

Is there any special term for such a system?  I suppose it's more specific than just "system of equations", since a general system might not have a closed-form solution, or any solutions at all.

Comment: "closed-form solvable" would seem most apt or convenient. It's short and expresses everything you want to say.

Comment: Thanks.  I just realized, though, that there is an additional restriction: all variables must be explicit in the equations (one can always isolate for any of the variables in the equation).  Would "explict closed-form solvable" be correct here?

Comment: I  think you are correct : "explicitly closed-form solvable"